# State retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Não sou muito de perguntar, né, mas isso está tirando o meu sono...
Tenho a seguinte função para formatar datas

```
const DataFormat = (props) => {
    const data = props.split('T');
    const [year, month, day] = data[0].split("-")
    const formateddata = day + " de " + month + " de " + year
    return "Atualizado em: " + formateddata
}

export default DataFormat
```

Enquanto no outro:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../services/api'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import DataFormat from '../functions/dataformat'

const Produto = () => {
    const { listaId } = useParams()
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    useEffect(async () => {
        const response = await api.get(`getproduto/${listaId}`)
        setList(response.data)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="titleBox">
                <p className="updatedTime">{DataFormat(list.updatedAt)}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Produto
```

Esse updatedAt até me retorna a data certa, mas quando passa dentro da função ele vira undefined D:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Aguardo ansiosamente pela solução ;'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no seu `useEffect`. Pode parecer estranho, mas não é possível fazer o `useEffect` funcionar assíncrono dessa forma. Dito isso, o erro esta ocorrendo justamente por que o valor de `list.updateAt` ainda não foi atualizado quando passado para a função `DataFormat`. O jeito correto seria esse:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAPI() {
        const response = await api.get(`getproduto/${listaId}`)
        setList(response.data)
    }
    fetchAPI()
}, [])
```

Duas dicas:

1. Pode ser interessante utilizar bibliotecas específicas para se trabalhar com datas, recomendo o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).
2. O nome correto da sua função seria `dateFormat`, com "e" no lugar do "a". A tradução de "data" é "dados".